# Squared multiplication of Quaternion

Tags: quaternions

I am reading a book on the math behind game engine. At the end of the chapter that talks about quaternions they are some exercises.
I need to prove that $||q_1q_2||^2 = ||q_1||^2||q_2||^2$

It should be farely simple but I'm stuck on probably the dumbest thing. How I proceed :

Let $q_1 = v_1 + s_1$ and $q_2 = v_2 + s_2$. V is a 3d vector and s a scalar.

Then $||q_1q_2||^2 = (v_1\times v_2 +s_1v_2+s_2v_1)^2+(s_1s_2-v_1\cdot v_2)^2$

I can already see the LaGrange identity simplifying the annoying part but I apparently clearly don't understand how the distribution works in this case.

For example if I take the last part I would like to expand it as $(s_1s_2)^2+(v_1\cdot v_2)^2-2
(s_1s_2(v_1\cdot v_2))$ but the book expands at as $(s_1s_2)^2+(v_1\cdot v_2)^2$.

Of course how I distribute the terms makes me unable to give the proper answer but I don't understand why it doesn't work how I think. I am clearly missing some knowledge or I am very tired but I would need help to understand why I can't do what I want here.

Screenshot of the official answer :
[image: Answer from the book]

Comment: This looks strange.  What is your definition of the norm?  (In the standard one, this is a straightforward calculation.)

Comment: Can you do it for complex numbers?

Comment: @Randall let q* be the conjugate of q : $q^* = -v + s$ then

$qq^*=q^*q=v^2 +s^2$ so

$||q||=\sqrt{qq^*}=\sqrt{v^2+s^2}$

Comment: The simplest proof of $\|q_1q_2\|^2=\|q_1\|^2\|q_2\|^2$ is obtained by representing the quaternions as [complex $2\times 2$-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) and using the fact that quaternion multiplication is ordinary matrix multiplication and $\det q$ is nothing else than the squared length of the quaternion.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes I understand that, I searched on the internet the other ways of proving that but my issue is understanding how the book did it. Specifically how they expanded the second part of the equation.
I added to the question a screenshot of the official answer.

Comment: What an insanely complicated proof for such a simple thing... Why not just use $\| q_1 q_2 \|^2 = (q_1 q_2)(q_1 q_2)^* = q_1 q_2 q_2^* q_1^* = \cdots$ instead?

Comment: The book does **not** expand $(s_1s_2-v_1\cdot v_2)^2$ as $s_1^2s_2^2+(v_1\cdot v_2)^2$. Rather, the book cancels the $-2s_1s_2v_1\cdot v_2$ we get from expanding the square $(s_1s_2-v_1\cdot v_2)^2$ with the $+2s_1s_2v_1\cdot v_2$ we get from expanding the square $(v_1\times v_2+s_1v_2+s_2v_1)^2$. Do you see what happens to the other things we get from expanding $(v_1\times v_2+s_1v_2+s_2v_1)^2$?

Comment: @HansLundmark I started from the multiplication $q_1q_2 =v_1 \times v_2 + s_1v_2 + s_2v_1+ s_1s_2 - v_1 \cdot v_2$. That is how the mult is represented in the book so that q is still a vector and a scalar since quaternion is used for rotation and other transforms.

Comment: @runway44 You mean that $(s_1v_2)(s_2v_1) = s_1s_2(v_1\cdot v_2)$ ? Implied multiplication of vectors is a dot product not a outer product ? If yes, it explains why I am lost.